# Check for signature on module before alter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have signed modules in SQL Server 2008 databases. In case someone alters signed modules (proc or trigger) i want to print information message, that has to re-sign procedure and print TSQL code to do that (there are appropriate rights).

How and what is the best way to do that?

DDL triggers seems no to be suitable for this need, as inside trigger module is already altered and think i can not find out if it was signed before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the whole idea of the signature is that someone *authorized* has reviewed the module (inspected the code) and then used his authority to sign the module. Altering the module requires the same authorized individual to review the module again, check for conformance and re-sign. Automating this process pretty much defeats the purpose of code signing, just make everybody sysadmin and call it a day.

Comment: in my opinion while the database is being developed it is acceptable- developer has rights to use certificate for code signing. when code is deployed on real system- of course, code is signed after review and private key back-up'ed and removed not to be accessible.

Comment: And in any case- if the developer alters signed module, it would be nice to let him know that he have done something, that can cause problems.

Comment: Well isn't then the *developer* responsibility to sign the module? Why does he needs to be 'let know' he did something?

Comment: There is many, many modules, some of them has to be signed. And it happens, that people forget to re-sign module. Just to make life easier! + I dont want to automate module signing, i want to print message, that has to be done!

Comment: [Event Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182602%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or [DDL triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) are the way to go. You can automate the signing in dev using event notification, you must have a table that contains the list of modules that require signing and sign them automatically. Ie. don't rely on discovering that signing is required but instead *know* that is required. You can build the list *now* from [`sys.crypt_properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189536%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Know this is an old question, but there are other reasons to use signed SPs. Here is an answer to the question 'how to determine if SP is signed':

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sys.crypt_properties 
    WHERE (crypt_type = 'SPVC') AND 
       (major_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo_or_schema].[WhateverYourSPIsCalled]'))) 
    -- <stuff to do when SP is signed>
ELSE -- <stuff to do when SP is not signed>
```

Worked this out thanks to Remus (see comment on other answer).

Comment: But this will not work in a DDL-trigger as they are AFTER triggers :(